# Kinect Studio - inject data without a sensor connected

Tags: kinect

When using kinect studio without a sensor connected, the studio will not find the instance of the app like it does when using it with a sensor connected.

My goal is to be able to test stuff in my program without having to connect the actual sensor.

Anyone knows what do I have to do to make my app be able to work offline with the xed file?

I am currently using kinect for windows 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play back Kinect Studio .xed files in Kinect Studio without a Kinect sensor, but you cannot connect to an application or force the recorded data into the application without a Kinect sensor.

If you really need to run your application without a sensor, you would have to create your own data recording and playback feature in your application. For example, after the Kinect SDK provides you data, serialize and optionally compress it to a file or series of files. Later, you would have to have your application load and playback the files through the same application code path but not involving the Kinect SDK.